# How to build an S3 item writer with Spring Batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-batch, batch-processing

I would like to write in S3 directly from Spring Batch (csv file with FlatFileItemWriter), the same question has already been asked here: 
[spring batch file writer to write directly to amazon s3 storage without PutObjectRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685891/spring-batch-file-writer-to-write-directly-to-amazon-s3-storage-without-putobjec)

But it remains unanswered.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I answered the question you linked. You can remove this duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test and I'll let you know :)