# class org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource cannot be cast to class org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud

I was using Spring batch (3.1.0) for my project. The requirement is to write the output file directly to GCP bucket. Using a custom writer:

```java
public class GSWriter implements ItemWriter<String> {

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    private WritableResource resource;

public GSWriter(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, String resource) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
        this.resource = (WritableResource) this.resourceLoader.getResource(resource);
    }

@Override
    public void write(Chunk<? extends String> items) throws Exception {

        try (OutputStream outputStream = resource.getOutputStream()) {
            items.forEach((item) -> {
                try {
                    outputStream.write(item.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I pass the resource `URL(gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{file.csv})`, I get the `ClassCastException`.

```
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [com.equifax.dfca.cdms.configuration.GSWriter]: 
Factory method 'writer' threw exception with message: 
    class org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource cannot be cast to 
    class org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource 
    (org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource and 
    org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
... 25 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    class org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource cannot be cast to 
    class org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource 
    (org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource and 
    org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    
    at ...
```

Comment: `I was using Spring batch (3.1.0)`: There is no version 3.1.0 of Spring Batch, the 3.x line stopped at 3.0.10. Do you mean Spring Batch 3.0.10 or is it Spring Boot 3.1.0? Please check this and also share the version that you upgraded to, to be able to tell what has changed between the two versions.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Basically it is 3.x version.

Comment: Update : GoogleStorageResource instead of Resource resolved this particular exception. Currently I am facing issue with custom writing. Using your approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685891/spring-batch-file-writer-to-write-directly-to-amazon-s3-storage-without-putobjec file is being writing over and over again in bucket. I need to write the final output file in bucket rather than each chunk. @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: Good to hear using `GoogleStorageResource` solved the issue. May be add an answer with that so that people in the same situation know how you resolved the issue. Regarding `Using your approach file is being writing over and over again in bucket. I need to write the final output file in bucket rather than each chunk.`: I did not try that writer, just gave it as a starting point. Have you tried to extract the output stream from the write method? I will update that answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947585/5019386. Hope it helps now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the dependency,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

use this bean for the resource object,

```
import com.google.cloud.spring.storage.GoogleStorageResource;
@Bean
public GoogleStorageResource getResource() {
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID).build().getService();
    return new GoogleStorageResource(storage, "gs://" + BUCKET_NAME + "/" + filname.txt);
}
```

In custom writer,

```
public class GSWriter implements ItemWriter<String> {
private final Resource resource;
public GSWriter(WritableResource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
}
```